# How to modify class member in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing a simple `Binary Search Tree` in Javascript, but I couldn't get my head around the Javascript OOP way of doing things.
In my `insertHelper` method, I assigned to root a new `BinaryNode` but after the function returned, it was still `null` even I explicitly used the `this` pointer within `insert` method. So could anyone help me explaining this?

```
function BinaryNode(key, value, left, right) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}

function BinarySearchTree() {
    this.root = null;
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.insertHelper = function (root, key, value) {
    if (root === null) {
        root = new BinaryNode(key, value, null, null);
    }
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.insert = function (key, value) {
    this.insertHelper(this.root, key, value);
    if (this.root === null) {
        console.log("root is NULL!");
    }
};

var bst = new BinarySearchTree();
console.log(typeof bst);
console.log(typeof bst.root);
bst.insert(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, `this.root` being `undefined` is a special case you have to handle explicitly. I'll let you figure out how to finish implementing `insertHelper` now.

The problem with the way you were doing it was you were reassigning a scope variable whereas you needed to reassign the variable on the `this` object.

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.insert = function (key, value) {
    if (this.root == null) {
        this.root = new BinaryNode(key, value);
    } else {
        this.insertHelper(this.root, key, value);
    }
};
```

Comment: Hm, why do we need to separate the logic of insert here? Could you explain?

Comment: @Chan Because reassigning `root` in `insertHelper` will not change `this.root` and only affect root in the scope of `insertHelper`

Comment: @Chan—including *root* in the formal parameter list is the same as declaring it in the function with *var* (more or less). So assigning to *root* assigns to the local variable, not the the *root* property of the *this* object. If you didn't create *root* as a local variable, then when you assign to it a new global variable called *root* will be created and the value assigned to that. The difference is that the resolution of identifiers on the scope chain (i.e. variables) is very different to that for identifiers for object properties (on the `[[Prototype]]` chain).

Comment: @RobG: Interesting, thanks a lot. I think I understand it a bit better now.

Answer (score 3):

Have a try:

Change:

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.insertHelper = function (root, key, value) {
    if (root === null) {
        root = new BinaryNode(key, value, null, null);
    }
}
```

To:

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.insertHelper = function (root, key, value) {
    if (root === null) {
        //change root to this.root
        this.root = new BinaryNode(key, value, null, null);
    }
}
```

When you pass on the variable "this.root", in the body of insertHelper, the variable "root" just were regarded as **local variable**, so, "this.root" was not changed，still "null".